# Update with innerjoin giving error

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi giving incorrect syntax near keyword 'INNER' for the below query.

```
UPDATE ObjectNotes
SET ObjectNotes.NoteHeaderToken=146 
INNER JOIN po ON ObjectNotes.RefRowPointer = po.RowPointer
WHERE ObjectNotes.NoteHeaderToken=145
AND  po.stat='O'
AND ObjectNotes.SpecificNoteToken=577804
```

Comment: sorry From is missing in the query thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
UPDATE ObjectNotes 
SET ObjectNotes.NoteHeaderToken=146 
FROM  ObjectNotes  INNER JOIN po ON ObjectNotes.RefRowPointer = po.RowPointer 
WHERE ObjectNotes.NoteHeaderToken=145 AND po.stat='O' AND   ObjectNotes.SpecificNoteToken=577804
```